# How do I use pytorch view to preserve the groupings of a dimension?

Tags: pytorch

Given an arbitrary tensor, how do I preserve one of its dimensions when reshaping? By preserving a dimension, I mean if we have an (n,m) rectangle, the groupings along the row dimension would be all groups of n elements, and the groupings along the column dimension would be the group of m elements.

More concretely, given a 4d tensor

```
x = torch.randn(4,2,3,5)
```

I want to reshape such that all the groupings of "5" are together like this:

```
y = x.view(-1, 5)
```

But how do I get the grouping of 5's if the tensor is (4,5,2,3) or (4,2,5,3)?

Answer (score 0):

I bet you can use `permute` function, like:

```
x = torch.randn(4,5,2,3)
x = x.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)  # (4,2,3,5)
y = x.view(-1, 5)  # reshape
```